# Find the location of a systemd unit file service

Tags: systemd

There are many different places where systemd unit files may be placed. Is there a quick and easy way to ask systemd where it read a service’s declaration from, given just the service name?

Answer (score 173):

For units that are defined in actual, static files, this can be seen in `systemctl status`:

```
$ systemctl status halt-local.service
● halt-local.service - /usr/sbin/halt.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/halt-local.service; static)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

But there are units that are not defined by files, e.g. with `systemd-cron` installed. These have no useful location listed with `status`:

```
$ systemctl status cron-jojo-0.timer
● cron-jojo-0.timer - [Cron] "*/10 * * * * ..."
   Loaded: loaded (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/jojo)
   Active: active (waiting) since Mon 2015-05-18 14:53:01 UTC; 9min ago
```

In either case, though, the `FragmentPath` field is educating:

```
$ systemctl show -P FragmentPath cron-daily.service
/lib/systemd/system/cron-daily.service
$ systemctl show -P FragmentPath cron-jojo-0.service
/run/systemd/generator/cron-jojo-0.service
$ systemctl show -P FragmentPath halt-local.service
/lib/systemd/system/halt-local.service
```

Comment: How about the path of some mask service? (not all of them are in /lib/systemd/system or /usr/lib/systemd/system)

Comment: Good, but partial, answer. But FragmentPath can be empty, e.g:
systemctl show -p FragmentPath subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device

Comment: You can also use `-p` instead of `-P` if you prefer to see `FragmentPath=` before the response.

Answer (score 33):

You could cat the systemd unit. This shows the file location as comments. Bonus: It also shows overrides.

```
systemctl cat sssd
# /lib/systemd/system/sssd.service
[Unit]
...

# /etc/systemd/system/sssd.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
...
```

Comment: Neat, especially with the override! As my other solution it does not work for stuff like `net-devices-eth0.device`.

Answer (score 1):

This below one gives multiple file locations

> `show`  -- Show properties of one or more units/jobs or the manager
>
> `-p` `--property=NAME`     Show only properties by this name

```
$ systemctl show -p FragmentPath {accounts-daemon,ntp,sshd}
FragmentPath=/lib/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service
FragmentPath=/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service
FragmentPath=/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
```

Comment: Note that `systemctl show -p FragmentPath {accounts-daemon,ntp,sshd}` becomes `systemctl show -p FragmentPath accounts-daemon ntp sshd` after the shell performs [brace expansion](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (using nullmailer as an example):

```
systemctl show nullmailer | grep FragmentPath | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'
```

That will produce something like this:

```
/lib/systemd/system/nullmailer.service
```

Then to see the service file content, you could do this:

```
cat $(systemctl show nullmailer | grep FragmentPath | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
```

And that would produce something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=nullmailer


[Unit]
Description=Nullmailer relay-only MTA

... stuff omitted for brevity ...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Hope it helps.

PS. I typically put those commands in an alias file just for convenience.

P.PS. As Joaquin mentioned, you can use the -P flag instead of using the grep|awk combo I was using/mentioning.

```
systemctl show nullmailer -P FragmentPath
```

Comment: Why do you use `grep` and `awk` when `systemctl` supports `-P` to print just one field?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner - well, I learned something today. Thanks!